# ItextSharp-How to give Color and Bold to paragraph

Tags: c#, itext

```
Phrase p1Header = new Phrase("Hello World", FontFactory.GetFont("verdana", 15, Font.BOLD));
```

It just makes `Hello World` bold. I want to give the color to it as well.

Comment: Sounds like you want SO to do your homework...?

Comment: Have a look at `FontFactory` - this class has many overloads of `GetFont`; simply use one that has both a *style* and a *color* argument.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.

```
Phrase p1Header = new Phrase("Hello World",FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 10, Font.BOLD, new Color(255, 255, 255)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the font and add to the Paragraph

```c#
iTextSharp.text.Font myFont= FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 255));
Paragraph myParagraph = new Paragraph("MyField", myFont);
```