# C# iTextSharp (How to build a paragraph mixing different fonts)

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to add multiple paragraphs to a cell with different fonts in C# , but I don't know how to do it.

```
label.LabelText = $" {asseblynumber}               EWAK {ewak} Qty.{quantidadepecas}\n Part Number\n {Part_Number}\n Assembly Name\n {assemblyname}\n Material\n {material}\n Fornecedor\n {manufacturer}\n";
```

I wanted the `assembly name`, `Material`, `Fornecedor` to be bold.

I am expecting something like this:

> **Part Number**
> 1141414141
> **Assembly Name**
> dwad21412412awda
> **Material**
> 14142141ad1412w
> **Fornecedor**
> adada2424sa

to put this text in a label

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/82/itextsharp-adding-text-with-chunks-phrases-and-paragraphs and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41951305/itextsharp-how-to-give-color-and-bold-to-paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Tested on iText7 (7.2.5)

Im not sure if it's possible to do it by the "$" operator.
You need to define each paragraph.

1. Set the PdfFonts
2. Create a cell
3. Use them in the required paragraphs
4. Add paragraphs to the cell
5. Add a cell to the PDF document

```
PdfFont normal = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.TIMES_ROMAN);
PdfFont bold = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.TIMES_BOLD);

Cell cell = new Cell();

Paragraph partName = new Paragraph("Part Number");
partName.SetFont(bold).SetFontSize(20).SetFontColor(ColorConstants.RED);
cell.Add(partName);

Paragraph ewak = new Paragraph("1141414141");
ewak.SetFont(normal).SetFontSize(15);
cell.Add(ewak);

    .
    .
    .
    .

document.Add(cell);
```